# how do I highlight an excel cell after 2 repetitions of a value in same column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
1----Serial No.
2----123
3----123
4----124
5----125
6----123
7----125
8----128
9----125
```

In this case cell no. 6 and 9 should be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your data is in column A, select from row 2 downwards and apply conditional formatting using the formula

```
=countif($A$1:$A1,A2)>=2
```

Comment: No, no, It's not my question, I want to highlight only the occurrences after first two (not all). As shown in the example

Comment: did you even try what I suggested? that's what it does

Comment: Was going to remove my answer in favor of this, but I cannot replicate -- it looks like it highlights the second thru second to last occurrence when there are more than 3 of a unique value

Comment: with respect you must not have done it correctly. it would do what you describe if you selected from row 1 downwards but I did say row 2 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, your data is in column A and starts in cell 1, you can add the following formula to cell `B3` and fill down :

`=AND(A3=A2, A2=A1)`

Then, Autofilter on column B for cells with value `TRUE`, and highlight the corresponding cells in column A.